# Duplicate Apple APNS push notifications?

Tags: php, iphone, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

We've been using APNS on our app without much incident for some time now, and suddenly our users are reporting receiving the same push notification multiple times.

I've confirmed - tediously - that our servers are only sending the notification payloads to Apple once, and yet the notification produces 2 and sometimes 3 identical alerts, both in the banner and notification center.

This has been observed in both iOS5 and iOS6.

Has anybody seen this phenomenon before?  Am I perhaps missing some opportunity to add a unique identifier to the payload that will prevent Apple from sending duplicate notifications to the device? Google's C2DM has collapse_key for this sort of thing, but I can find no reference to a similar functionality in APNS.

Comment: Did you try to contact apple on this issue?

Comment: I would check the server code just to be sure that everything is fine on your side, also just for testing purposes you could include some info into notification body, maybe creating date?

Comment: Yeah, I checked the server code and added unique identifiers to the push notification payloads. I confirmed with complete confidence that we're only sending these notifications to Apple once.

Comment: Any luck on this issue? Seeing the same thing...

Comment: Looks like users of the gmail app are experiencing this issue also: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/x-AIvOGGR68 . I think it must be an Apple bug.

Comment: I also problems encountered problems with duplicate push notifications. There are more than a handful smart people that has been debugging the push server. No duplicates are sent to APNS :(

Comment: You can try modify the php script and pick the latest device registered by latest update time incase of duplicates, and generate message for the latest picked device only..

Comment: Just Revoke Production Push SSL Certificate and generate a new license this will help

Comment: I am having the same problem - sometimes there are two alerts instead of one and there is no way for me to avoid that. Did anybody find a solution?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18074529/duplicate-push-notifications-on-ios gives a decent answer by referencing the gmail thread (see @ToddH above) -- Also I noticed that some apps coalesce identical push notifications into something like "You've received two messages"

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to replicate this issue? You should try and add identifiers to notification if it's not a productions server. Also check if user doesn't have mutiple logins in your database. For eg. With twitter, Facebook and password etc and all have same device token.

Had a similar issue some time back and digging deep I found that these users had multiple editions of beta iOS firmware on their phone beside final version and this was causing apple servers to send same notification to Same device ID mutiple times.

Some blogs have instructions for consumers out there and very litte we could do.

Comment: I added an identifier (carefully; it is a production server) and confirmed that the same push notification is arriving.  I can prevent the extra push notifications from causing repeat logic on the app, but what I can't stop is the notifications from popping up on the Notifications Center.

Comment: I don't think our users have multiple beta iOS firmware editions, but I'm happy to explore any possibility. Do you happen to have any links to the blogs with instructions?  I can try those out myself on devices.

Comment: For me, this is not a real answer. Just a little bit of speculation.